# Codeigniter, uploading multiple files with same name

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, upload

I have an upload form that allows me to add as many files as needed. However when I start trying to upload the files I get an error.

**Controller**

```
$this->load->library('upload'); 
$error = "";
$file  = "";
$this->total_count_of_files = count($_FILES['user_certificates']['name']);
print_r($_FILES['user_certificates']['name']);

for($i=0; $i<$this->total_count_of_files; $i++)
{
    $_FILES['user_certificates']['name'] = $_FILES['user_certificates']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['user_certificates']['type'] = $_FILES['user_certificates']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['user_certificates']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['user_certificates']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['user_certificates']['error'] = $_FILES['user_certificates']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['user_certificates']['size'] = $_FILES['user_certificates']['size'][$i];

    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
    $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['user_certificates']['name'];
    $config['upload_path'] = './certificate_files/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'txt|pdf|doc|docx';
    $config['max_size'] = 0;

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $status = 'error';
        $msg = $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
    else
    {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $file = $data['raw_name'] . $data['file_ext'];
    }
    if($file)
    {
        $status = "success";
        $msg = "Image successfully uploaded";
    }
    else
    {
        $status = "error";
        $msg = "Something went wrong when saving the image, please try again.";
    }
}   
echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));
exit();
```

The `print_r($_FILES['user_certificates']['name']))` shows me the files I have added:

```
Array ( [0] => license.txt [1] => license.txt )
```

I am totally stuck on how to get the upload to work. Any ideas?

Cheers in advance!

EDIT

If I change this:

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
```

to this:

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('user_certificates'))
```

it works, but only for one file, it doesn't seem to loop round again for some reason

Comment: What's d **error** you are getting???

Comment: The file is not getting uploaded to any folder, and the 'echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));' shows '{"status":"error","msg":"Something went wrong when saving the file, please try again."}'. So the error is originating from after the config is initialized. Any idea?

Comment: It seems your file is getting uploaded but from where are you setting value for `$data['raw_name']`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loops seems to be incorrect.

```
...
$_FILES['user_certificates']['name'] = $_FILES['user_certificates']['name'][$i];
...
```

these lines overwrite the original $_FILES array, so after completion of first loop, it will not find anything else in the loop because it got overwritten.

Instead you may first store the $_FILES array to a local variable and loop through it to upload one by one.

Comment: Any idea how I would go about fixing that?

Comment: As I suggested, you can store the $_FILES in a temp variable before starting the loop, like $temp = $_FILES, and loop through $temp, then inside loop you initialize your $_FILES variable using the temp variable. Try it out. If it doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: Ah excellent, that worked! Thank you very much, such a little change makes a huge difference!